# iOS Swift: Google Maps Height animation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm having a problem animating the height constraint of a view containing Google Maps.

I have the following structure:

- grandFather container view
- father container view
- son container (google maps) view

son has equal height of father and is centered by x and y.
father has equal height of grandfather and is centered by x and y.

I'm doing some height constraint animation on the grandfather height. Everything resize perfectly except for the google maps (son) that after the resize it does a kind of refresh on the height constraints and it's look ugly.

This is the code of the animation:

```
self.mapContainerHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.height + coverHeight
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (_) in
                completion?()
            })
```

This after the last iOS Update. I don't know if this is linked..

Any tip?

Like is shown by the images for less than a seconds I see the top "sand" bar and than it resize again properly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us the final view image ?

Comment: @AymanIbrahim updated

Comment: @TheMiotz I have the same problem. Map doesn't animate smoothly. It jumps at the end of animation. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mkkrolik Did you ever figure out a way to resolve the jump at the end of the animation? I'm having this same problem after I animate the height of my mapView's frame.

Comment: @JohnDeLong the only solution i found was changing height manually without using animation. So I was changing height by 1 let's say every 0.01 second. But it was lagging and did not work as i expected :/ If you will find any other solution let me know.

Comment: @mkkrolik Thanks for your reply. Upon a colleague's suggestion this morning, I was able to resolve my issue! For my case, I have a pull up drawer that behaves just like the google maps app. When the drawer comes up, I was trying to resize the map view to fill the remainder of the screen. So instead of resizing the map view, I kept the mapView's frame size the same, and just updated the bottom padding so that it moved up with my drawer's animation. For me, this solution worked perfectly. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks @JohnDeLong. I don't know why I didn't think of that. It seems that is still the only way to solve this.